# PHP unique sessions

Tags: php, php-5.3

Hi how do I use a unique hash for session's ? like when I do an if statement :

```
if ($_SESSION['BOOTY'] != 0){ 
 echo Nice $_SESSION['BOOTY'];
}
```

it wont work. How to do a comparison of unique hashes with an if statement ?

Comment: Hmm please explain your question in some more detail, can we have an example of this hash, what is it used for etc. also *what is **BOOTY*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using `isset()` method instead of equating to zero ...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['booty']))
```

Comment: but that would be to allow any var, which is insecure.

Comment: Because only you (in detail: your application) can change the content of a session, the value of a key is as insecure as the one you put in it.